# MySQL: sql query / procedure to get accumulated rooms for each hotel on the basis of total number of rooms booked

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a products which facilitate to book rooms in different destinations, hotels for selected dates. I've all the information available in my db and it's working fine in all scenarios except last one.

- **One Rooms (Working Fine):** User can search hotels with one room (2 Adults)
- **Multiple Rooms with same occupancy (Working Fine):** User can book more than one rooms but same occupancy in each rooms(like: 3 rooms and each room have 2 Adults)
- **Multiple Rooms with different occupancy (Not Working):** In that case user is looking for 3 rooms in a hotel and all has different occupancy (like: `Room1: 2 Adults`, `Room2: 1 Adults`, `Room3: 3 Adults`). I've information (Room info with their capacity either for 1 / 2 / 3 paxes with price) for each available rooms (rooms also has their types like: single Bed / double standarnd) for every hotels in my db.

Now problem is to display in rooms, Since I've individual info for all available rooms (room and their occupancy## Heading ##) in my db but I've to display accumulated results to the end user. Means I've to group / combine those rooms (may be of different room type) which fulfil the user requirements.

Below is the Ex for a booking:

User is looking for 3 rooms with different occupencies (7 paxes)

**Ex:**

**Room1:**  2 Adults  1 Child

**Room2:**  3 Adults  0 Child

**Room3:**  1 Adult   0 Child

Below is the information available in db. Now want to combine all those rooms within a hotel which has at least `1 Room with 2AD & 1CH` and `1 Room with 3AD` and `1 Room with 1AD` and have to display in with total price.

**Note:** Combination should be on minimum price.

Expected Result:

**For Hotel Id: 1**

Possible combination can be (ID) :

`1,2,4` //Correct or most preferable because id 1&2 has same rootype & Board. So here we have meet our criteria of roomCount=3 and all occupancy=7 TotalPrice = 324.75

`1,3,4` // this scenario is only preferable if same roomtype and boardCode not available

Here we can say in Hotel id: 1 we have only 1 room available which can be combination either 1,2,4 / 1,3,4

Same for other hotels.

[DB Snippet Please Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJFW4.jpg)

**[SQL Fiddle Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cc04/1/0)** for sample DB schema

Here is my Procedure, It gives me expected results but the only problem is with cursors which are fixed for 3 Rooms (I declared 3 cursors) while user can look for 1 to 10 rooms with different occupancy. Can you please help me make it dynamic so that I could fetch records for any numbers of Rooms.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getRoomInfo()
BEGIN
DECLARE id1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE id2 INTEGER  DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE id3 INTEGER  DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE price1 decimal(6,2) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE price2 decimal(6,2) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE price3 decimal(6,2) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE hotel_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE cur_hotel CURSOR  FOR SELECT hoteId FROM booking_rooms GROUP BY hoteId;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR  FOR SELECT id, price FROM booking_rooms WHERE totalAdults = 1 AND hoteId=hotel_id ORDER BY price;
DECLARE cur2 CURSOR  FOR SELECT id, price FROM booking_rooms WHERE totalAdults = 2 AND hoteId=hotel_id AND totalChildren=1 ORDER BY price;
DECLARE cur3 CURSOR  FOR SELECT id, price FROM booking_rooms WHERE totalAdults = 3 AND hoteId=hotel_id ORDER BY price;


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS combinations;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE combinations (hotelId INT, id VARCHAR(100), price DECIMAL(10,2)) ENGINE = Memory;

OPEN cur_hotel;
hotel_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur_hotel INTO hotel_id;
    IF done=1 THEN
        LEAVE hotel_loop;
    END IF;
    OPEN cur1;    OPEN cur2;    OPEN cur3;
    cycle_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO id1, price1;
        FETCH cur2 INTO id2, price2;
        FETCH cur3 INTO id3, price3;
        IF done=1 THEN
            set done=0;
            LEAVE cycle_loop;
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO combinations(hotelId, id,price) 
            VALUES (hotel_id, CONCAT_WS(',',id1,id2,id3),price1+price2+price3);
     END LOOP cycle_loop;
    CLOSE cur1;
   CLOSE cur2;
  CLOSE cur3;
 END LOOP hotel_loop;
CLOSE cur_hotel;

SELECT * FROM combinations;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE combinations;
END
```

Please let me know if you need additional information

Your help is really much appreciable.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thanks,
I've added SQL Fiddle link with sample data. Can you please provide the solution. Your help will be much appriciable.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cc04/1/0

Comment: You missed the part in Strawberry's guide where it writes to provide what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. See the following guidance why your "question" is getting down and close votes. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've put my code, Want to correct this code so that I could get expected results dynamically.

Comment: Your solution is flawed. If a room has more accommodation than is required, it won't show up in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
SELECT DISTINCT room1.hoteid
              , room1.id r1
              , room2.id r2
              , room3.id r3
           FROM booking_rooms room1 
           JOIN booking_rooms room2
             ON room2.hoteid = room1.hoteid
            AND room2.id <> room1.id
           JOIN booking_rooms room3
             ON room3.hoteid = room1.hoteid
            AND room3.id <> room1.id
            AND room3.id <> room2.id

          WHERE room1.totaladults >= 2 AND room1.totalchildren >= 1
            AND room2.totaladults >= 3 AND room1.totalchildren >= 0 
            AND room3.totaladults >= 1 AND room3.totalchildren >= 0;
          ORDER 
             BY room1.totaladults + room2.totaladults + room3.totaladults
              , room1.totalchildren + room2.totalchildren + room3.totalchildren
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08cc04/7

Note also that price would normally be DECIMAL, and room count, totalAdults, and totalChildren would all be TINYINT

Comment: I put my procedure which is giving me correct results as expected, but the only problem is with the fixed rooms. As I'm looking for 3 Rooms, I declared 3 Cursors while I just want to make it dynamic so if user is looking for max 10 rooms, can get results for all 3 rooms.

Comment: Well it's a combinatorial problem- not the kind of thing for which sql is best suited. The strategy I've outlined works, but doesn't scale particularly well.

Comment: Any other solution which I can implement to get the results.